# How to insert all the nested attributes in bulk using rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, bulkinsert

I have a report model like this :-

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report_clients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_clients, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['client_id'].blank? },  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And report client model is like

```
class ReportClient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
end
```

In the time of report creation my parameter structure will be like

```
Report.create({name: params[:name],  report_clients_attributes: [{client_id: 1}, {client_id:2}]})
```

It will run 1 query to insert report and 2 queries to insert report_clients.

Generally I used to insert 1000 report_clients against each report which leads to 1000 sql queries.

I know, I can solve the problem using bulk insert by writing raw sql insert. But wanted to know if, is there any other way / better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Been through a similar scenario, there is an awesome gem [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) for these type of cases.

```
report = Report.new(name: params[:name])
report.save_with_nested_attributes(report_clients_attributes)
```

In `report.rb`

```
def save_with_nested_attributes(report_clients_attributes)
  report_clients_objects = []
  transaction do
    save!
    report_clients_attributes.each do |client_attributes|
      report_clients_objects << report_clients.new(client_attributes)      
    end
    ReportClient.import(report_clients_objects)
  end
end
```

There are many other ways mentioned in the [gem wiki](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) to mass import records.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @RSB for your help . Will the validation for report model will work in this case.

Comment: Yes it runs validations, you can either use `save!` or add the nested clients under `if save`. I added everything under `transaction` block to handle and other database errors.

Comment: When i want to run  ReportClient.import(report_clients_objects)
it is showing 
 ***Class Create Many Without Validations Or Callbacks***

Answer (score 0):

As I've outlined in more detail [in this blog post](https://keygen.sh/blog/how-to-bulk-insert-nested-attributes-in-rails/), you can bulk insert nested attributes using an override of the model's [`autosave_associated_records_for_#{relation}`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L188) method.

```rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report_clients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_clients,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: :blank?

  def autosave_associated_records_for_report_clients 
    return if report_clients.empty?

    ReportClient.insert_all(
      report_clients.map { |r| { report_id: id, client_id: r.client_id } },
      record_timestamps: true,
    )
  end 
end
```

By default, this would only be run on `:create`, but can be used for `:update` as well if you add `autosave: true` to the relation. Though you would need to handle associated records that are `marked_for_destruction?`, and delete them accordingly, otherwise it would be insert-only. You may also want to look into `upsert_all`, since duplicates can be updated or skipped.

Another thing to note is model validations — they aren't run with `insert_all`. Keep that in mind. You may be able to run model validations manually, but bulk insertion is best used alongside strong database constraints.

Lastly — this is using an internal (i.e. private) Rails API, but it hasn't changed in 9 years.

Answer (score -5):

You may use create as follows

```
Report.create({name: params[:name],  report_clients: report_clients})
```

where report_clients is defined as

```
def report_clients
        clients = [{client_id: 1}, {client_id:2}]
        clients.map do |client|
          ReportClient.new(client)
        end
end
```